# Error by npm run deploy_contract

Tags: nodejs, npm

am having an issue!
I am getting a catch error ( catch ERROR: ERROR STATUS: 403) when I ran "npm run deploy_contract"

> 10k-collection-video@2.0.0 deploy_contract
> node utils/nftport/deployContract

Is all REQUIRED contract information correct in config.js? (y/n): y
CATCH ERROR: ERROR STATUS: 403
Retrying
CATCH ERROR: ERROR STATUS: 403

I am stuck and cant get a solution
am using  codeSTACKr /create-10k-nft-collection V2.0 from get hub
but sadly no reply from codestackr
thank you

as requested
more details and info
I followed the instructions of this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=quGdJweadFM
till deploy contract  on 22:10 min
github address also on you tube channel
https://github.com/codeSTACKr/create-10k-nft-collection
everything else went as the video stated
thank you

best regards

you might need this

```js
const path = require("path");
const basePath = process.cwd();
const fs = require("fs");
const yesno = require('yesno');

const {
  fetchWithRetry,
} = require(`${basePath}/utils/functions/fetchWithRetry.js`);
const {
  CHAIN,
  CONTRACT_NAME,
  CONTRACT_SYMBOL,
  CONTRACT_TYPE,
  MINT_TO_ADDRESS,
  METADATA_UPDATABLE,
  ROYALTY_SHARE,
  ROYALTY_ADDRESS,
} = require(`${basePath}/src/config.js`);

const deployContract = async () => {
  const ok = await yesno({
    question: `Is all REQUIRED contract information correct in config.js? (y/n):`,
    default: null,
  });
  
  if(!ok) {
    console.log("Exiting...");
    process.exit(0);
  }

  if (!fs.existsSync(path.join(`${basePath}/build`, "/contract"))) {
    fs.mkdirSync(path.join(`${basePath}/build`, "contract"));
  }

  try {
    const url = `https://api.nftport.xyz/v0/contracts`;
    const contract = {
      chain: CHAIN.toLowerCase(),
      name: CONTRACT_NAME,
      symbol: CONTRACT_SYMBOL,
      owner_address: MINT_TO_ADDRESS,
      type: CONTRACT_TYPE,
      metadata_updatable: METADATA_UPDATABLE,
      royalties_share: ROYALTY_SHARE,
      royalties_address: ROYALTY_ADDRESS,
    };
    const options = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(contract),
    };
    const response = await fetchWithRetry(url, options);
    fs.writeFileSync(`${basePath}/build/contract/_deployContractResponse.json`, JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
    if(response.response === "OK") {
      console.log(`Contract ${CONTRACT_NAME} deployment started.`);
    } else {
      console.log(`Contract ${CONTRACT_NAME} deployment failed`);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`CATCH: Contract ${CONTRACT_NAME} deployment failed`, `ERROR: ${error}`);
  }
};

deployContract();
```

Comment: add more info please. What framework are u using? What inside deploy contract script, link to GitHub

Comment: i have updated my question. hope that is what you are asking,thank you. Best regards

Comment: Is all REQUIRED contract information correct in config.js? (y/n): y
CATCH ERROR: ERROR STATUS: 403
Retrying
CATCH ERROR: ERROR STATUS: 403
Retrying
CATCH ERROR: ERROR STATUS: 403
Retrying
CATCH ERROR: ERROR STATUS: 403

Comment: many have a similar problem. https://github.com/codeSTACKr/create-10k-nft-collection/issues/157 read the comments please and try to ask them what they did. I#m sorry but I don't think that anyone here will spend time debugging a problem in a tutorial of another developer